# Rejecting class because it failed compile-time verification Android

Tags: android, synchronized-block

One of my application suddenly fails on startup, with the following error message :

> java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class
>   com.sample.BufferManagerImpl because it failed
>   compile-time verification (declaration of
>   'com.sample.BufferManagerImpl' appears in
>   /data/app/com.sample.myapp-1/base.apk)

It only fails on devices using the ART virtual machine, but not on Dalvik

Comment: Possible related Issue on AOSP Issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=InstantRun%20VerifyError&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=202347

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is due to having a `synchronized` block inside a `try-catch` block, for example :

```
try {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        updateState();
    }
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
}
```

Apparently this is not a good practice, but as soon as I change it like this it works :

```
synchronized(mLock) {
    try {
        updateState();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in android studio 2.1 ,the instant run will cause this problem,just run after close the instant run function.

File -> Preferences > Build Execution -> Deployment -> Instant Run

Disable the first checkbox:
   Enable Instant Run to hot swap.....

Answer (score 2):

If you are building with Jack, make sure it's turned off from build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    jackOptions {
        enabled false
    }
}
```

Comment: This would break lambdas though.

Answer (score 1):

This error also might happen due to usage of Mockito within an Android InstrumentationTest. If the error appears on mocking objects then you have to add this lines to you gradle-file:

```
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4"
```

This works for me with Mockito 1.10.15 and 1.10.19.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem to with **android 5**. my app did correctly on 4 or below but on android 5 devices i had crash.

i broke my codes with multiple `Threads` and it fixed.
if your code wants to change the **UI** use **handler** .

```
 Thread Thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    use this if your codes will change the Ui
```

.
.
.
.
.