# Android Studio have error with mail.jar and additionnal.jar and activation.jar

Tags: java, android, email

I have imported my project from Eclipse to Android Studio
but my app won't run:

> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage' appears in /data/data/com.ipAndroid.Settinge/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex)
>                                                                                   at com.ipAndroid.Settinge.Mail.send(Mail.java:120)

my project send gmail

Answer (score 4):

The problem stems from android studios. Here is how I was able to fix it (disable the hot swap instant run)

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/instant-run

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes. (first checkbox)

(based on the instant run comment found here : [Rejecting class because it failed compile-time verification Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455162/rejecting-class-because-it-failed-compile-time-verification-android))