# VerifyError: Rejecting class android.support.g.b because it failed compile-time verification

Tags: android, proguard

This is similar to [Rejecting class because it failed compile-time verification Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455162/rejecting-class-because-it-failed-compile-time-verification-android) and [java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class on Lollipop when using release APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031905/java-lang-verifyerror-verifier-rejected-class-on-lollipop-when-using-release-ap) but the origin of my problem is still unknown and all the proposed solutions do not help.

Manually installing a signed release apk with MultiDex support and ProGuard enabled throws this exception on start:

```
475-475/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                            Process: ..., PID: 475
                            java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class android.support.g.b due to bad method void android.support.g.b.<init>() (declaration of 'android.support.g.b' appears in /data/app/...-2/base.apk)
                                at ...MyApp.attachBaseContext(Unknown Source)
                                at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181)
```

This will not happen with `-dontoptimize`. Current minimal optimization setting:

```
-optimizations "code/*"
```

I get the same error without `-optimizations` or with less restrictive options. Adding `-keep class android.*` wont help either. I get no error with `"code/removal/*,code/simplification/*"`, but this ignores `-assumenosideeffects`

android.support.g.b is the obfuscated android.support.multidex.MultiDex class itself, and the error is caused when the overridden `attachBaseContext(Context)` is called:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {

    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Decoding this method (the default constructor) with the byte code viewer results in:

```
private b() { // <init> //()V
    return
}
```

- It would be useful to disable optimization by class specification.
- Alternative: Knowing the minimum `-optimizations` option that considers `-assumenosideeffects`

Comment: was this solved? Get a similar error with Android X libraries

Comment: Any solution? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use member wildcards with `-assumenosideeffects` because this will "spill over" to Object  for other classes. See https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/716/#98d4

Similar problems may come up for any rules with interfaces. Example:

```
-assumenosideeffects class * implements Interface {
    public <init>();
    public Object interfacemethod(); # May concern methods with same signature in other Objects
}
```