# app stopped once open when create signed apk android studion

Tags: android, android-studio

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class android.support.v4.graphics.b because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'android.support.v4.graphics.b' appears in /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/base.apk)
        at android.support.a.a.a(MultiDex.java:298)
        at android.support.a.a.<clinit>(MultiDex.java:79)
        at com.technivance.q84sale.base.controller.manager.a.attachBaseContext(BaseApplication.java:71)
        at com.forsale.forsale.controller.manager.ForSaleApplication.attachBaseContext(ForSaleApplication.java:112)
        at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:205)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:988)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:620)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5082)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30455162/6950238) question and answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rejecting class because it failed compile-time verification Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455162/rejecting-class-because-it-failed-compile-time-verification-android)

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko every thing was working fine , the problem only happen when I try to generate signed app, also the answer you sent is from 3 years ago